# Converting command line CURL command to PHP script

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to convert the following curl command to a PHP script.

```
curl -v -c cookies.txt -d "username=XXXX&password=XXXX&login=true&redirectMethod=POST&product=home.betfair.int&url=https://www.betfair.com/" https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/login >out.txt 2>&1
```

When I execute that command in terminal the cookies.txt and out.txt files are both correctly created. However when I try in PHP I cant get it to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$fields = [
'username' => "lainga9",
'password' => "0a6c4822",
'login' => 'true',
'redirectMethod' => 'POST',
'product' => 'home.betfair.int',
'url' => 'https://www.betfair.com/'
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/login',
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

No files are created though - anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the response in the file you want, in regards to out.txt. In regards to the cookiejar though, the cookies.txt file is likely a permissions issue and apache cannot write to the folder.

You can ensure apache can write via this command in the proper directory:

```
sudo -u apache touch cookies.txt
```

Here is what you'd add to the bottom to write the response to a file:

```
file_put_contents('out.txt', $response);
```